# How can I add a new parameter to existing model and try to optimize it on tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a synthetic time series data and created a model for forecasting, used GRU and LSTM in TF 1.x. Instead of that, I would like a create a  different data using my original data. This new data will be multiplication of a matrix ( and this matrix is a function of a parameter "a" ) and the original data. Imagine, original data is Nx1 and the matrix NxN , so new data will be Nx1 as well. Now my question is on how to learn optimum "a" beside weights and bias.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Input` layers and `Lambda`.

*e.g.*

```
my_data = Input(shape = (n, 1))
my_matrix = tf.Variable(your_numpy_array)

new_data = Lambda(tf.matmul)[my_data, tf.transpose(my_matrix)]
```